# Backbone view fails to render Kendo UI in IE8

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, internet-explorer-8, kendo-ui, marionette

I am debugging a project that I created with Backbone, Marionette and Kendo UI.  All is well until I have check it in IE8.  The initial page renders but as the region's view changes the new Kendo element doesn't render to the page.  Each new view is created dynamically with backbone and a template. The data itself is static for the charts and graph.

Does anyone have an idea to what maybe causing the new view to not render the kendo properly. Here is a link to a test version of the project. Just click the button to proceed to the part I was referring.

http://cabanapps.com.br/apps/vale-dashboard2014/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that kendo was generating the charts but were not render properly on IE8.  By using the redraw() method for kendo's charts i could get the graphics to display properly.  I simple made a delayed call to the redraw method to correct the problem.